# Gemalto Tokens Conflict: Unable to Access Multiple Web Applications Simultaneously

Tags: windows-11, multi-factor-authentication

I'm encountering an issue with accessing two separate web applications, both utilizing Gemalto tokens for multifactor authentication. Here's the scenario:

I'm using Windows 11 and both applications, let's call them Application X and Application Y, are web-based.

When I plug both Gemalto tokens into my PC and attempt to access Application X, I successfully enter the token password and log in. However, when I subsequently try to log into Application Y using the other token, it appears that Application Y is identifying the token meant for Application X, preventing me from logging in.
Things I've tried so far:

Attempted to log into Application Y first, followed by Application X, but the issue persists.
Tested different browsers including Firefox, Edge, and Chrome, but encountered the same problem.
Cleared cache and browsing data without success.
I'm seeking advice on how to resolve this issue. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!